# First page header

Tags: header-footer

I need again your precious help.
In particular, I was wondering how to make a first page header. 
The result that I would like to obtain is something like this:

[image]

In the picture, I used a word processor, but the title/author layout should be the standard one. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want it at one page you can place some nodes and enter some text in it.

### Example with boxes draw:

[image]

### And without the boxes:

[image]

### MWE (without boxes drawn)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\author{Roald}
\title{Header test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle  
    \tikzstyle{header} = [minimum height=2 cm, minimum width=2 cm, text width=1.5 cm, align=center]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[header, below right] at (current page.north west) {Left text. An then some.};

        \node[header, below left] at (current page.north east) {Right text. And then some};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```